# Entity Framework Core fails to recognize Key Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using .Net Core 3. Brand new project, with Identity.

I've made a simple new entity to add to the database. I get the following error on startup. As you can see, I have already added the [Key] attribute to the entity and it will still not register.

[image]

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<LocationRecord> LocationRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LocationActivity> LocationActivities { get; set; }
}
```

And the model class:

```
public class LocationActivity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id;
    public DateTime Moment { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public int Confidence { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Id is a field rather than a property. Try rewriting like so:

```
public class LocationActivity {
     [Key] 
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     .......
```